# PHP Tidy and Character Encoding

Tags: php, character-encoding

I am making use of PHP tidy like so:

```
$config = array(
                'wrap'                         => 0,
                'lower-literals'               => 1,
                'preserve-entities'            => 1,
                'drop-empty-paras'             => 0
                );

$tidy = new tidy;

$tidy->parseString($html, $config, 'utf8');

$tidy->cleanRepair();
```

When I pass in HTML with English text it comes out fine. However, French text, and it has trouble with the encoding. So if I pass something like `vérifier` then it appears as `vÃ©rifier` in the output. How can I get tidy to play nice with all languages, at least latin ones.

In addition, I will be passing the output of tidy through to PHP's DOM Document, anything I should be careful with here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks very much like the UTF-8 handling is working fine, but you're interpreting the result in latin-1 instead of UTF-8. Set an appropriate HTTP header or meta tag instructing the browser to read the document using UTF-8.

```
header('Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: actually you are right. It is my Google syntax highlighter that is causing the issue! More specifically its `htmlentities` that is the issue so that I can show the HTML in a `pre` tag.

Comment: @Abs `htmlentities` takes a character set as its third parameter, you might want to try that.